# Trying to understand OVAL data

Tags: rhel, security

In the redhat OVAL data I can see XML's like this,

```
  <criteria operator="AND">
   <criterion comment="bind is earlier than 32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.4" test_ref="oval:com.redhat.rhsa:tst:20170063030"/>
   <criterion comment="bind is signed with Red Hat redhatrelease2 key" test_ref="oval:com.redhat.rhsa:tst:20100975006"/>
  </criteria>
```

This is clearly used for version comparing, but the version above in the comment is `32:9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.4`

Does anyone know what `32:` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `32:` in the XML comment corresponds to the [epoch tag](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-tags.html#S3-RPM-INSIDE-EPOCH-TAG) of the bind RPM.